# What happens if a kalashtar eats a dream pastry?

Tags: dnd-5e, eberron, curse-of-strahd

According to *Eberron: Rising from the Last War:*

> Kalashtar sleep, but they don't connect to the plane of dreams as other creatures do. Instead, their minds draw from the memories of their otherworldly spirit while they sleep. As such, you are immune to spells and other magical effects that require you to dream, like *dream,* but not to spells and other magical effects that put you to sleep, like *sleep.*

Meanwhile, for dream pastries (*Curse of Strahd,* chap. 6):

> A creature that eats one in its entirety must suc­ceed on a DC 16 Constitution saving throw or fall into a trance that lasts for 1d4 + 4 hours, during which time the creature is incapacitated and has a speed of O feet. The trance ends if the affected creature takes any dam­age or if someone else uses an action to shake the crea­ture out of its stupor.
>
> While in the trance, the creature dreams of being in some joyous place, far removed from the evils of the world. The places and characters in the dream are vivid and believable, and when the dream ends, the affected creature experiences a longing to return to the place.

So what happens if a kalashtar eats a dream pastry? Obviously they don’t dream. Do they fall into the trance? If so, what do they experience?

Alternately put, does the dream pastry’s trance *require* the dream, or are trance and dream mechanically separate (though related)? If they are separate, what happens to a kalashtar when they eat one?

Comment: Related: [A PC in Curse of Strahd is cursed by Mother Night and eats a dream pastry. What happens?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176069)

Answer (score 13):

A dream pastry's trance is not sleep; it's a specific kind of trance. It's more like a drug trip than anything related to rest, so there's no reason it would necessarily work differently on creatures that don't sleep or dream (including Warforged, if you going to be looking towards an Eberron/Ravenloft crossover). A magically-induced hallucination isn't *necessarily* the same thing as sending your mind to the plane of dreams (or whatever your particular game's cosmology has), even if the item itself uses the word 'dream' to describe the experience.

That said, Kalashtar do dream, they just dream *differently* from most creatures. If a DM wanted to rule that instead of a normal joyous dream, they dream the memory of a peaceful time in the long past of the spirit that lives inside them, that wouldn't be wrong, but there's nothing in the rules about it one way or the other.

Comment: I like this answer. It’s simple and neat, and it keeps things working the way that they’re intended. That said, I’m not fully convinced that dream pastries induce a hallucination/drug trip. The description says the consumer dreams, and it calls the experience a dream. Further, while I’m unfamiliar with hallucinogenics, my understanding is that a hallucination is something you see that’s not there, while the experience of being someplace you’re not is more the realm of dreams.

Comment: A full sensory experience is still hallucination. If you want to get real technical, a waking dream is  a pseudohallucination because it isn't confused with reality, but that's getting into specific medical terminology. In any case, we're in fantasy-world here so "illusion", "hallucination", "vision", whatever word you particularly like. I'm just saying the use of the term 'dream' is to quickly explain the effect to the reader and may not reflect the technicalities of how it actually functions in-universe.